# NewRelic: Transitioning Health Status of APM Apps from Red to Grey

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, newrelic, newrelic-platform, newrelic-synthetics

I need to delete some of my APM apps and for this I need the APM apps to transition to Grey Health Status. I followed the steps mentioned in this [forum](https://forum.newrelic.com/s/hubtopic/aAX8W0000008Y3tWAE/disabled-agent-apps-still-green#-14) and have been waiting patiently for hours but still the Red Health Status of the APM apps are not transitioning to Grey.

What I did on my Amazon Linux 2 ARM64 EC2 instance:

```
1. Disabled newrelic in newrelic.ini:

newrelic.enabled = false

2. Rebooted Server

3. Stopped newrelic-daemon:

sudo /etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon stop
```

Please let me know what needs to be done for transitioning the APM Apps Health Status from Red to Grey so that I can delete them.